# Toolbar very small in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuI9F.png)

Why is my toolbar so small?
I couldn't find how to change this in Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a larger toolbar in NetBeans just right click the toolbar, then uncheck the **Small Toolbar Icons** menu entry from the popup menu:

[image]